# libqtcore4: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) -- "trying to overwrite shared `/etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf`"

Tags: 16.04

After upgrading from 14 to 16 I am now getting this:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Selecting previously unselected package libqtcore4:amd64.
(Reading database ... 282007 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqtcore4:amd64 (4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf', which is different from other instances of package libqtcore4:amd64
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Trying to remove the deb package results in this:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 282007 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqtcore4:amd64 (4:4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite shared '/etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf', which is different from other instances of package libqtcore4:amd64
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqtcore4:amd64:
 libqtcore4:amd64 depends on qtcore4-l10n; however:
  Package qtcore4-l10n is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libqtcore4:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libqtcore4:amd64
```

Comment: To resolve your dependency problem see https://askubuntu.com/questions/252777/how-can-i-resolve-dpkg-dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a reboot everything worked again.

Answer (score 2):

I've been having a problem with this for a couple months and this little line fixed everything. I wish I'd have read this sooner!

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite  /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.7+dfsg-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a [Launchpad Ubuntu tracker for this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt4-x11/+bug/1193243). This is the posted workaround, which also worked for me:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf /etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf.old
sudo apt-get -f install
```