# issues with mysql

Tags: 16.04, mysql, openvz

I am having issues with MySQL. I tried to reinstall but get the following.  this is an openvz vps that I have upgraded to 16.04.

```
$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libencode-locale-perl
  libevent-core-2.0-5 libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl
  libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl
  liblwp-mediatypes-perl libnuma1 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl
  mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7
  mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  libdata-dump-perl libipc-sharedcache-perl libwww-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libencode-locale-perl
  libevent-core-2.0-5 libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tagset-perl
  libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl
  liblwp-mediatypes-perl libnuma1 libtimedate-perl liburi-perl
  mysql-client-5.7 mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server
  mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
0 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/18.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 162 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 21432 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaio1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libaio1_0.3.110-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaio1:amd64 (0.3.110-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnuma1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libnuma1_2.0.11-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnuma1:amd64 (2.0.11-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.7_5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb                                  ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.7_5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.7.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.7_5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb                                  ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libevent-core-2.0-5_2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64                                 .deb ...
Unpacking libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.c                                 nf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.7.
(Reading database ... 21607 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-tagset-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhtml-tagset-perl_3.20-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liburi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../liburi-perl_1.71-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liburi-perl (1.71-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-parser-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhtml-parser-perl_3.72-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-parser-perl (3.72-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-pm-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libcgi-pm-perl_4.26-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-pm-perl (4.26-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfcgi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libfcgi-perl_0.77-1build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfcgi-perl (0.77-1build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-fast-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libcgi-fast-perl_1%3a2.10-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.10-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libencode-locale-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libencode-locale-perl_1.05-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-template-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhtml-template-perl_2.95-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (2.95-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtimedate-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libtimedate-perl_2.3000-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libtimedate-perl (2.3000-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-date-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhttp-date-perl_6.02-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhttp-date-perl (6.02-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libio-html-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libio-html-perl_1.001-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libio-html-perl (1.001-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblwp-mediatypes-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../liblwp-mediatypes-perl_6.02-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.02-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-message-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhttp-message-perl_6.11-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhttp-message-perl (6.11-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Setting up libaio1:amd64 (0.3.110-2) ...
Setting up libnuma1:amd64 (2.0.11-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libevent-core-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-2ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my                                 .cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
insserv: warning: script 'wide-dhcpv6-client' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'bind9' missing LSB tags and overrides
Job for mysql.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control                                  process. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en                                 abled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Thu 2017-05-04 21:42                                 :21 EDT; 8ms ago
  Process: 14530 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=e                                 xited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 14529 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=killed, signal=KILL)
  Process: 14521 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exi                                 ted, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 14529 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

May 04 21:42:21 tanganyika systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
May 04 21:42:21 tanganyika systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 04 21:42:21 tanganyika systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 's...'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-2) ...
Setting up liburi-perl (1.71-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-parser-perl (3.72-1) ...
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.26-1) ...
Setting up libfcgi-perl (0.77-1build1) ...
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.10-1) ...
Setting up libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.95-2) ...
Setting up libtimedate-perl (2.3000-2) ...
Setting up libhttp-date-perl (6.02-1) ...
Setting up libio-html-perl (1.001-1) ...
Setting up liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.02-1) ...
Setting up libhttp-message-perl (6.11-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
andy@tanganyika:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
insserv: warning: script 'wide-dhcpv6-client' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'bind9' missing LSB tags and overrides
Job for mysql.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control                                  process. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en                                 abled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Thu 2017-05-04 21:52                                 :23 EDT; 14ms ago
  Process: 15015 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=e                                 xited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 15014 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=killed, signal=KILL)
  Process: 15006 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exi                                 ted, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 15014 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

May 04 21:52:23 tanganyika systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
May 04 21:52:23 tanganyika systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 04 21:52:23 tanganyika systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 's...'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
```

Comment: Maybe duplication: https://askubuntu.com/questions/252777/how-can-i-resolve-dpkg-dependency

Comment: are you still with this problem, have you fixed it?