# sudo apt-get install apache2 - doesn't work

Tags: apt, software-installation, apache2

Running:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Result with:

```
 * Apache2 is not running
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "reload" failed.
apache2_invoke headers: already enabled
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                                                                                         [fail]
 * The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "restart" failed.
 * Reloading web server apache2                                                                                                                  * 
 * Apache2 is not running
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "reload" failed.
dpkg: error processing package gosa (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gosa-plugin-ssh:
 gosa-plugin-ssh depends on gosa; however:
  Package gosa is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gosa-plugin-ssh (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 gosa
 gosa-plugin-ssh
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
ramana@lenovog500:~/KM_GIT/bbb/iot/mysql$ ^C
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tired to install it multitude of time, or do you have some other server installed already??If so, you need to shot down or delete that other server, (if you want to use Apache as a local host) When I had the need to do fresh install Apache web server I had only fallowed this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-q8Jj4aAWYw&t=100s

Answer (score 0):

dpkg seems to have a dependency problem with gosa-plugin-ssh

```
Package gosa is not configured yet.
```

try

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
```

Good explanations on the following answers:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/253115/219213
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109703