# Two services allocated for the same bus name org.bluez

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, ubuntu-mate

When I run `sudo apt upgrade` on my Ubuntu MATE 20.04, I get the following:

```
[various stuff]
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up bluez (5.53-0ubuntu3.7) ...
Failed to restart bluetooth.service: Unit bluetooth.service failed to load properly: File exists.
See system logs and 'systemctl status bluetooth.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "restart" failed.
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: error (Reason: Unit bluetooth.service failed to load properly: File exists.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Dec 20 14:30:21 ada systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services allocated for the same bus name org.bluez, refusing operation.
[Above error appears 9 more times]
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
 installed bluez package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bluez
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I Resolve dpkg dependency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252777/how-can-i-resolve-dpkg-dependency)